# Simple FileChooser application for tomcat server?

Tags: tomcat

I have installed a Tomcat 5.5 server on a remote linux machine.

I would like to create a simple webpage/application where a user can press a button and then a FileChooser box pops up which allows him to specify a file on his local machine that he can then upload to the webapps folder.

When the file is uploaded a simple script should be executed doing some predefined operations on the file.

Are there any tutorials for creating such a small tomcat uploader webpage?

Answer (score 0):

This is not as trivial as it seems. However, you may want to have a look at `manager` application that comes with tomcat. It provides an ability to deploy, undeploy and re-deploy web applications dynamically.

http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-5.5-doc/manager-howto.html